# .htaccess redirect url with # (angularJS) - how to fix redirect loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, loops, redirect

Here is the line in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /business  http://yatko.com/business#/
```

- this will obviously cause a redirect loop, what is the best method to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: For web server it will get `business` in both cases. Is it okay to add a query parameter to stop looping?

Comment: Yes, the only case this should redirect is when the URL ends with business or business/ if there is anything else following, the redirection should stop.

Comment: Right but after redirection if `/business` is becoming `/business#/` in the browser but web server will get `/business` both the times hence it will cause redirection loop. So I think you may need to redirect `/business` to something like `/business/?r=1#/` to prevent looping.